# remove the mysql server

Tags: mysql

```
root:~# sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cryptsetup : Depends: plymouth but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: kbd but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: console-setup but it is not going to be installed
 dmsetup : Depends: util-linux (> 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: udev (> 141-2) but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: util-linux (>= 2.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
 initramfs-tools : Depends: udev (>= 147~-5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: util-linux (> 2.15~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd-services (= 204-5ubuntu20.9) but it is not going to be installed
 libsolid4 : Depends: udev but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: upower but it is not going to be installed
 mountall : Depends: udev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: plymouth but it is not going to be installed
 udisks2 : Depends: udev but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: policykit-1 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: first run 'apt-get -f install'then try to remove mysql and then purge

Answer (score 0):

First of delete the user created 

    `sudo deluser mysql
    sudo delgroup mysql`

then stop the processes of the mysql

    `sudo service mysql stop  #or mysqld
    sudo killall -9 mysql
    sudo killall -9 mysqld
    sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get autocleansudo deluser mysql
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
    sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5
    sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5`